# Take screenshot with Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, screenshot

I'm trying to take a screenshot with my application. But I get the following error message :

```
QPixmap: Must construct a QGuiApplication before a QPixmap
```

My program runs in the background and I do not want a GUI. How would I create a "QGuiApplication" and then hide the window permanently ? Or is there another way to take a screenshot without having to create a GUI ?

I was using the following code to take the screenshot :

```
QScreen *screen;
QPixmap qpx_pixmap;

screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
qpx_pixmap = screen->grabWindow(0);
screenshotTarget = dir.path() + "/" + QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("dddd hh:mm:ss");
qpx_pixmap.save(screenshotTarget);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an instance of `QGuiApplication` on startup, *before* you create your `QPixmap`. You don't need to also create a GUI. `QGuiApplication` itself will not create any windows or anything visible.

A good place for that is at the start of `main()`:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    // ...
```

It also works with `QApplication`, since it inherits from `QGuiApplication`. It just provides extra things needed for creating `QWidget` based objects, which you don't need. The important thing is that the `QGuiApplication` object is created *before* the `QPixmap`.

Finally, you need tell `grabWindow()` which part to grab. To grab the whole screen, use:

```
auto geom = screen->geometry();
qpx_pixmap = screen->grabWindow(0, geom.x(), geom.y(), geom.width(), geom.height());
```

Comment: My program runs with a QGuiApplication instead of the QApplication I was using before. So it works. My screenshot is not taking, but I'll debug that. Thanks

Comment: @pHeoz It also works with `QApplication`, since it inherits from `QGuiApplication`. It just provides extra things needed for creating `QWidget` based objects, which you don't need in your case. The error message suggests you're creating the pixmap object too early. You need to create it *after* the `QGuiApplication` object.

Comment: @pHeoz Updated the answer. You also need to tell `grabWindow` the part of the window you want to grab.

Comment: @pHeoz Your compiler doesn't support C++11? I really advise you update. Or add `CONFIG+=c++11` in your project file in case your compiler supports it but your Qt version is old. Anyway, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#geometry-prop where it tells you the type is `QRect`.

Comment: I got it to work, thanks. I'm using Qt Creator 3.6.1. I had installed it on my machine a long time ago. But I think the CONFIG+=c++11 would have worked. I ended up using QRect anyway.